# Dividing through when optimising?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm given the following question:

> "The point $(3,4)$ solves the problem of maximising the function $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2$, s.t. the constraint $x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le 25$ for some values of $a_1$ and $a_2$. Find these values."

- When I worked through it you get the ratio of the partial derivatives as: $\frac{f_{x_1}}{f_{x_2}}$ = $\frac{2x_1}{2x_2}$ = $\frac{2(3)}{2(4)}$ = $\frac{6}{8}$ = $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$
- Therefore $a_1 = 6$ and $a_2 = 8$

However just out of habit I simplified the fraction getting $a_1 = 3$ and $a_2 = 4$

I assume this is wrong? And I assume it's wrong because while the ratio of the coefficients does = $\frac{3}{4}$ you can't just take these as the coefficient values. ***But I'm kind of struggling to put into words precisely why it's wrong, other than that "I guess it's just clearly wrong and I shouldn't do that."***

Would love some (probably quite basic) clarity.

Comment: Your solution is not wrong. It only requires more rigor. The optimization (maximization or minimization) of an objective function $f(x)$ is equivalent to the optimization of $kf(x)$ for a constant and positive $k$. In case of a bilinear obj. function $a_1x_1+x_2x_2$, knowing the ratio $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ or $\frac{a_2}{a_1}$ is sufficient (the case of $a_1=0$ or $a_2=0$ or both, however, should be regarded carefully).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MostafaAyaz so are you saying if I wrote the values 3 and 4 for a1 and a2, rather than the given answer of 6 and 8, I would still be correct?

Comment: Exactly. And also you are correct for writing $a_1=3k$ and $a_2=4k$ for any $k>0$, e.g. $(a_1,a_2)=(15,20)$.

Comment: Actually @MostafaAyaz now I think about it, I  suppose this makes sense. Because let's say we take our plane in $R^3$ then any plane with that same ratio of coefficients will be maximised at that point (3,4) over the constraint. It's just that those maximum values will be different (as they are steeper and steeper planes for greater values of k, as mentioned in your latest note). Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This is an equivalent geometrical interpretation. Defining these planes as $a_1x+a_y+a_3z=0$, for a constant ratio of $\frac{a_2}{a_1}$ and $\frac{a_3}{a_1}$, these planes would be parallel and they only differ in the optimal value.

Comment: Hi @MostafaAyaz I briefly drew what I was trying to get at with the steepness of the planes. Two different planes, different gradients, but getting optimised at the same point over the constraint. https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/tqrjv8gr

Comment: With regards to your point about the ratio of the coefficients, and parallel planes, I think I see that as well.  Although I would have thought dividing through by $a_3$ would be more intuitive. I.e. $b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 = z$ Where $b_i = \frac{a_i}{-a_3}$. Then the constant ratio would give us the same coefficients (hence slope), but a different height for different z values. Is my understanding here correct? Appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: Hey there, @cormjack. For the first interpretation where you plotted the planes, note that  the coefficient $a_3$ can be determined in a way such that a constant ratio of $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ gives you the **same** plane. For example, with $(a_1,a_2)=(3,4)$, you can arbitrarily define a plane $3x+4y+z=0$. Now, with $(a_1,a_2)=(6,8)$, keeping the ratio of $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$ the same, another plane could be $6x+8y+2z=0$ or $6x+8y+az=0$ for $a\ne 2$. The first choice essentially gives you the first plane ($3x+4y+z=0$), whereas the second choice does not.

Comment: For your second interpretation, the parallelism is even more justifiable, since the lines $a_1x+a_2y=z$ can be regarded parallel for a constant $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$, only at different altitudes adjusted by $z$. So, these lines will have the same slope and your intuition is correct.

Comment: Amazing @MostafaAyaz, thanks again for your patience and time. Very generous of you! Not to push my luck, but Is there any chance I can tempt you with another question I have posted about convex optimisation and the KKT conditions?

Comment: That's very king of you. Of course, I will be glad to be of any help in my free time!

Comment: Wow thank you @MostafaAyaz, so here is one question that’s bothering me. Maybe just pick off pieces as you get time. Please just comment if it isn’t clear! Thanks! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607590/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-lagrange-optimisation