Sufficency of the KKT condition
This is a beginner question so I apologize.
The problem is to minimize $f(x,y) = 5x-3y$ subject to $x^2+y^2 = 136$.
Let the Langarian be $L(x,y,u) = 5x-3y+u(x^2+y^2-136)$
The KKT condition gives that either $(x,y,u) = (-10,6,1/4)$ or $(x,y,u) = (10,-6,1/4)$.
We can easily find that $(-10,6)$ is the minimum, but my question is this. My understanding is that if a point satisfies the KKT condition, then it is sufficient condition for it to be the minimum.
But how come we get two points here $(x,y,u) = (-10,6,1/4)$ and $(x,y,u) = (10,-6,1/4)$ that satisfies the sufficient condition for them to be the minimum(with only one of them being the minimum)?
Thank you.
EDIT: I'm working by this note: https://optimizationnotes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/convex_optimization/kkt.html
which says: The KKT conditions provides a sufficient condition for optimality. If a set of primal and dual variables
satsifies the KKT condition then they are the primal and dual solutions to the optimization problem.
And it certainly seems like both of the solutions satisfy the KKT conditions since we have no inequality constraint.

The standard KKT conditions are necessary, not sufficient. See discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607590/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-lagrange-optimisation

@whpowell96 isn't it necessary if strong duality holds? I'm going by this: https://optimizationnotes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/convex_optimization/kkt.html

That is correct but you haven't shown that for your problem.

In fact, this is a nonconvex optimization problem.

@BrianBorchers ah is it only sufficient when the inequality constraint and $f$ is convex and equality constraint is affine?
